# How to save result from navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition?

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3

I got some problems

I wanna get my current position and do somthing with it. I use navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition function like this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var current_location;
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position) { 
        current_location = position; 
    });

    // do something with current_location
});
```

But I cant assign possition to current_location. What' wrong? and can u show me how to assign the position value to an variable in order to use it out of navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition scope?

Thanks for ur help

p/s: my English is not very good :)

Answer (score 2):

Use this code for work with geolocation

```
if (navigator.geolocation) {
    // geolocation is available
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position) {
        do_something(position);     
    });

    function do_something(position){
        // use position.coords.latitude, position.coords.longitude there
        console.log(position);
    }
}
```

Comment: But i wanna save value of position (as an object) in order to use it any where I want outside the navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition scope. For example, if I could assign position to current_location I can acess current_location.address.country to display country in the View (MVC pattern)

Comment: I edited my code, check. In your variant you cant assign possition to current_location, because JavaScript - async language :) and When the code below '// do something with current_location' will be executed, current_location is not to be assigned. Use callback func (do_something in my code)